# Efficient way to compare 2 similar datasets

Tags: r, statistical-significance, anova, likert

I am a grad student who is fairly new to all of this. I have a matrix likert table that I was wanting to compare across 3 different relationships to the land. I got the means and standard error for all 3 groups, and I was wanting to run an ANOVA to compare each groups vs. the other groups, but I'm not really certain how to do that in R. Or if that's even the best approach.

For example, for landowners they rated confusion a larger limitation and ownership of data lower than the 2 farmer groups, but is this significant?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data isn't technically continuous (as it's a likert scale), but most fields treat likert as-if it were continuous, and you're a beginner, so an ANOVA is probably appropriate. Generally, you conduct a separate ANOVA for each outcome you're interested in, and correct for multiple comparisons across outcomes (for instance using an FDR correction). If you have a significant effect (generally p<0.05 after correction) and you want to know which group is driving that effect, you can do what are called *post-hoc* comparisons between groups. If you search for these terms online, you can find a number of [tutorials](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-do-post-hoc-pairwise-comparisons-in-r/) for how to do this in R.